# Problem with saving the product PrestaShop 1.7.6.7 + multistore

Tags: save, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, multistore

When saving the product (more precisely, changing the number of main items or in combination) with the multistore option enabled (only in the context of all stores), an error appears. Interestingly, after the second or next (how many stores in multi, how many times you have to click) the record goes correctly.

**Recreation:**

```
Go to BO >> set the shop context to >> "all shops"
go to the PRODUCTS tab >> edit the selected product >> change the STOCK (QUANTITY) to another >> click SAVE
I get a red message "Unable to update settings." and there is a problem with writing.
```

**I get an error in JS console:**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). 
There is no error in the NETWORK tab, despite the debugging mode enabled in Presta.
```

**Screenshots:**

```
https://prnt.sc/uj2uf2
https://prnt.sc/uj2ul7
https://prnt.sc/uj2v5f
https://prnt.sc/uj2w5v (headers)
https://prnt.sc/uj2w13 (preview)
https://prnt.sc/uj2vr8 (initiator)
https://prnt.sc/uj2vuk (response)
```

**Data for the demo version:**

```
This is the original, freshly installed version. 
Only the multistore has been enabled and one demo store has been added. That's all.

BO: http://bielizniana.pl/__test/admin758a9z7cn/
Login: test@test.pl
Password: test@test.pl
```

Comment: Which is the PHP value for `max_input_vars`?

Comment: max_input_vars 100000. All PHP settings on (phpinfo): https://bielizniana.pl/a.php

Answer (score 0):

You have set your multistore option "Share available quantities to sell" to NO.
This means when you are editing the product in All shops context it does not know what to do with your quantities.

Comment: Change this options...and error still showing when i save QTY in product :-(

Comment: this is probably related to one of the many multistore bugs of v1.7 (see https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/9723 )  especially with shared products between shops, it's way too hard debugging those issues in the core - my advice is to stay away from this feature until the team will not seriously get their hands on it